# stacked histogram with nested x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to create a stacked histogram with a nested x axis

[image]

I've tried with ggplot but so far haven't come close

As can be seen from the image above, I'm trying to make a histogram that
both show a total count per bin per year and the individual counts that make up 
the total count to be shown inside the bar

The individual counts that make the total are derived from the famtotal
column which are related to the FAMILY_DESC column

To sum it up I've been trying to make  cross between a histogram and 
a stacked bar chart

The next part is to have a nested x axis so there would be 6 bins and that
would be repeated for all the years

I hope this made sense and thank you very much in advance

```
structure(list(Year = c("2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015"), FAMILY_DESC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("ACROPORIDAE", 
"AGARICIIDAE", "DENDROPHYLLIIDAE", "EUPHYLLIDAE", "FAVIIDAE", 
"FUNGIIDAE", "MERULINIDAE", "MUSSIDAE", "OCULINIDAE", "PECTINIIDAE", 
"POCILLOPORIDAE", "PORITIDAE", "SIDERASTREIDAE", "UNKNOWN"), class = "factor"), 
    bin = c("five", "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", 
    "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", 
    "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", 
    "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", 
    "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", 
    "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", 
    "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", 
    "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", 
    "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", 
    "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", 
    "four", "one", "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", 
    "three", "two", "zero", "five", "four", "one", "three", "two", 
    "zero"), famtotal = c(0L, 1L, 87L, 1L, 4L, 136L, 0L, 1L, 
    35L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 33L, 8L, 12L, 64L, 0L, 1L, 37L, 
    1L, 8L, 20L, 0L, 2L, 88L, 3L, 6L, 122L, 0L, 2L, 57L, 4L, 
    9L, 16L, 0L, 5L, 43L, 4L, 15L, 81L, 0L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 7L, 
    25L, 0L, 1L, 57L, 4L, 9L, 100L, 0L, 6L, 38L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 
    0L, 0L, 29L, 8L, 8L, 47L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 2L, 4L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 
    65L, 1L, 14L, 124L, 0L, 2L, 29L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 0L, 5L, 38L, 
    4L, 5L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 6L, 18L), yeartotal = c(0L, 
    4L, 192L, 12L, 31L, 226L, 0L, 4L, 192L, 12L, 31L, 226L, 0L, 
    4L, 192L, 12L, 31L, 226L, 0L, 4L, 192L, 12L, 31L, 226L, 0L, 
    10L, 220L, 12L, 37L, 244L, 0L, 10L, 220L, 12L, 37L, 244L, 
    0L, 10L, 220L, 12L, 37L, 244L, 0L, 10L, 220L, 12L, 37L, 244L, 
    0L, 7L, 150L, 21L, 30L, 178L, 0L, 7L, 150L, 21L, 30L, 178L, 
    0L, 7L, 150L, 21L, 30L, 178L, 0L, 7L, 150L, 21L, 30L, 178L, 
    0L, 7L, 152L, 6L, 28L, 211L, 0L, 7L, 152L, 6L, 28L, 211L, 
    0L, 7L, 152L, 6L, 28L, 211L, 0L, 7L, 152L, 6L, 28L, 211L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -96L), .Names = c("Year", 
"FAMILY_DESC", "bin", "famtotal", "yeartotal"), vars = c("Year", 
"FAMILY_DESC"))
```

Comment: Could you paste your datafram as `dput(df)` instead of print ?

Comment: Good job with a drawn example of what you want. This is the absolute number 1 thing to do when trying to make a plot. Draw. It. By. Hand.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. Similar to the other good answer but with some major changes to imitate your scheme.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(bin, levels = c("zero","one", "two", "three", "four", "five")), 
              y=yeartotal, fill=FAMILY_DESC)) + 
  geom_col() +
  xlab("") +
  facet_grid(~Year, switch = "x") +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0,"cm"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Where `dat` is your data.frame, and `bin` would probably need to be re-ordered:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=bin, y=yeartotal, fill=FAMILY_DESC)) + geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

Although the heights do not quite correspond to your drawing.

Because you already have done the counting in bins, you do not want to use `geom_bar`, as it defaults to start counting. Instead we use `geom_col`.